# SuiteScript Select Line which does not exist returns an error

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0, clientscript

When I try to add new line and `selectLine()` it returns an error that ***SSS_INVALID_SUBLIST_OPERATION***
This is because that line is not exist. If I use `selectNewLine()` it works.
But I can't use this because I have already existing lines.
Is there any method that I can check if that line is new line or not by linekey please?

In Client script when the field is changed I try to get that value and change the next value.
I can't use `setSublistValue` because it returns me an error that function does not exist
So I try to get current record first and select the line and set field value

```
var record = currentRecord.get();    
record.selectLine({sublistId:"custpage_sublist1", line:lineKey});
record.setCurrentSublistValue({sublistId:'custpage_sublist1', fieldId:'custcol_2',  value:"TEST", ignoreFieldChange:true});
```

This returns an error when I try to add a new line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During line entry the fieldChanged and postSourcing functions already have the line selected. You can just use

`record.getCurrentSublistValue(...);`

You don't have to select the line because you are already there.